# Create a category archive page in TwentyTen Child Theme

Tags: theme-development, archives, theme-twenty-ten

I would like to create a page that will show all the posts from one particular category. I want to show the post title with the post thumbnail and content and nothing  else ..no other meta ..no post date, no author, no excerpt ,  nothing 
I have tried to follow various answers/tutorials without success leading  me to feel somewhat confused. 
Do I create a loop-category.php and add an if-category() statement for that category?? If so what statement please ?? please could someone explain clearly step by step Thank You

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, do you want this list of category posts on a special/specific page or are you just wanting to get control over the post listing on a native category archive, eg. `example.com/category/some-category` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don’t new »statements«. Take a look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display): WP does most of the work for you.

## 1. Find the name

Just create a new post list template, similar to your index.php and name it **category-slug.php**.

To get the **slug** part, go to `wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category` and look at the column named … slug.

[image: Screenshot]
[See the full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJjW9.png)

In my example image the slug for the category **Cat A** is **cata**, so your template’s name has to be **category-cata.php**.

## 2. Write the template

That is even easier: Include your usual suspects (header, sidebar, footer) and put a very basic loop inside.

### Sample code

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
get_header();
get_sidebar();
?>
<h1><?php wp_title(); ?></h1>
<ul class="postlist">
<?php
while ( have_posts() )
{
    the_post();
    ?>
    <li <?php post_class(); ?>><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php
    the_post_thumbnail();
    // If you need the full content, use
    // the_content();
    // wp_link_pages();
    the_excerpt();
    ?>
    </li>
    <?php
}
echo get_previous_posts_link(), get_next_posts_link();
?>
</ul>
<?php
get_footer();
```

WordPress will choose the template automagically, you have nothing more to do.

## 3. Style the template

In your theme’s header the element `body` or the element `html` (if you use HTML5 already) should have a call to [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class):

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

or

```
<html lang="<?php bloginfo('language'); ?>" <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Make sure your theme has it. On your new category archive the class attribute will look very similar to this:

```
class="archive category category-cata category-58 logged-in admin-bar"
```

Note the `category-cata`. You may now add special rules to your stylesheet (usually `style.css`) to change only this page.

#### Sample code

```
body.archive.category-cata
{
    background: #345;
    color:      #fff;
}
/* The thumbnails */
body.archive.category-cata .attachment-post-thumbnail
{
    float:      left;
    margin:     0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

And that’s all.